# Drupal 7 views two fields conditional filter functionality

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a view in Drupal 7 with many fields and with 2 date fields date_a and date_b.
I can't find a solution to implement a custom selection list filter where
display data based on these conditions below:

1. first value in selection list display data by date_a < now
2. second value in selection list display data by date_a > now
3. third value in selection list display data by date_b < now
4. fourth value in selection list display data by date_b > now

Is there any way to implement this functionality in a view with existing view functionality or with extended from a existing plugin like computed field etc?

Answer (score 0):

hey @niko did you tried [view conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional)